# How do I sum the values of two columns?

Tags: sql, oracle, join

here are two tables:

```
|column1|column2|
|------ |----   |
| A     |B      | 
|A1     |    B1 |
|A2     |B2     |
```

and

```
|column1a|column2a|
|------- |----    |
| A      |C       |
|A1      |C1      |
|A2      |C2      |
```

From this i want a
table like that:

```
|newColumn|newColumn2|
|------- |----       | 
| A      | B + C     |
|A1      |B1 + C1    |
|A2      |B2 + C2|
```

Hope you can help me ;)

Comment: your culumn type must be `integer` Check your column dataType

Comment: One row tables only? What do you expect to happen when more rows are added to each table?

Comment: What's expected to happen with newTable if someone later updates the table1 value to 44?

Comment: SQL table is an unordered set of rows. You cannot *vertically align* two tables without any *explicit* row order (some ordering criteria) or any other columns that express relationship between them

Comment: If they are really one-row tables, then `select sum(col1) from (select col1 from table1 union all select col2 from tableb) t`

Comment: in an explizit example I got one table with 20 rows

Comment: Please post your current attempt and describe what is the issue with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that *simple* case (is it really that simple? No additional rows in any of those tables?), then

```
SQL> select * from table1;

         A
----------
        10

SQL> select * from table2;

         B
----------
         2

SQL> create table table3 as
  2    select t1.a + t2.b as c
  3    from table1 t1 cross join table2 t2;

Table created.

SQL> select * from table3;

         C
----------
        12

SQL>
```

Comment: Hey, it was only a example for me. When I got a complex example : I got two Columns in both table like in Table1 we got x1 and y1 and in Table2 we got x2 and y2. Now we got in both tables 20 rows. The values in x1 and x2 are ids for example and similar (join partners). Now I want to add the values from y1 and y2 to one value y1+y2 . So the new Table consist of the columns x1  and y1 + y2 .How I do that?

Comment: Unfortunately, only you know what you really have, and we know what you tell us. If tables aren't that simple, please, **edit** the original question, post complete information, sample tables, rules that lead to desired result as well as that result itself.

Comment: Ok, my bad, but I just wanted to get a hint :/

Comment: That *was* a hint. You'll have to join tables, somehow. Cross join will produce Cartesian product so if (for example) TABLE1 has 5 rows and TABLE2 has 20 rows, the resulting TABLE3 will have 5 * 20 = 100 rows unless there are rules which would restrict that number.

Answer (score 2):

Cast your Column Value to `NUMBER`

```
SELECT CAST(table1.A AS NUMBER)+CAST(tableb.B AS NUMBER) as Sum
From table1 INNER JOIN tableb ON table1.Id=tableb.Id
```